# Cannot make vertical scrollbar always visible in usercontrol

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a usercontrol and I want that the vertical scrollbar is always visible. So first I set `AutoScroll` to `false`. Then I did this:

```
public MyUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    VerticalScroll.Visible = true;
}
```

This didn't work. The scrollbar was appearing/disappearing depending on the contents.

So I did this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool ShowScrollBar(IntPtr hWnd, int wBar, bool bShow);

private enum ScrollBarDirection
{
    SB_HORZ = 0,
    SB_VERT = 1,
    SB_CTL = 2,
    SB_BOTH = 3
}

public MyUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ShowScrollBar(this.Handle, (int)ScrollBarDirection.SB_VERT, true);
}
```

This didn't work either. So I tried another method:

```
protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnHandleCreated(e);

    var cp = base.CreateParams;
    cp.Style |= 0x00200000;
}
```

This also didn't work.

So how exactly can I always have the vertical scrollbar visible?

Comment: Did you manually add a *vertical scrollbar control* and it is not appearing when running the program?

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε No I didn't add a scrollbar manually.

Comment: Your code *cp.Style |= 0x00200000;* is not setting the params. It does nothing. You need to override *CreateParams* and return *cp* as in your code

Comment: Exactly, with both scrollbar styles if needed: `protected override CreateParams CreateParams { get { CreateParams parameters = base.CreateParams; parameters.Style |= (WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL); return parameters; } }`